# Set optional property for target

Tags: cmake

Is it possible to set an optional property for a target? (with or without a default value)

Consider this example:

```
add_executable(main main.cpp)
set_target_properties(main PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-DMY_FLAG=1")
```

After running cmake I can run `make main` and the macro `MY_FLAG` will be set to `1`.
But I would like to be able to set the value of the macro when running `make` using `make main -DMY_FLAG=5` or something alike.

To clarify further:
When writing a Makefile I can do something like

```
main: main.cpp
ifdef my_flag
  g++ main.cpp -o main -DMY_FLAG=$(my_flag)
else
  g++ main.cpp -o main -DMY_FLAG=1
endif
```

and then run either `make main` or `make main my_flag=5` and the macro will be set to either the default value of `1` or to `5`.
I would like to achieve a similar result with cmake.

Comment: Btw I really want to have an optional compile flag. So if the answer to this question is "no" but you actually can have an optional compile flag doing something different please let me know and I ask a new question (or change this one).

Comment: is it [option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/option.html) you are looking for?

Comment: That is an option (lol) but more than a boolean value would be really nice.

Comment: That option is specified at *CMake time* (via `cmake -DMY_FLAG=1 ..`), not when you run `make`.

Comment: Oh, right. I missed that. Of course at cmake time I can pass the flag with any type I want.